SSSD failing to start
I have installed SSSD in SUSE Linux for managing AD access. But for some reason, SSSD is not starting after joining to AD.
I have gone through almost every piece of documentation available.
Can someone provide guidance about what the cause behind it is?
Virtualization: amazon
Operating System: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:suse:sles:15:sp3
Kernel: Linux 5.3.18-150300.59.170-default
Architecture: x86-64

SSSD status
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-08-20 17:47:40 UTC; 30min ago
    Process: 944363 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sssd -i ${DEBUG_LOGGER} (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 944363 (code=exited, status=3)

Aug 20 17:47:40  systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
Aug 20 17:47:40  sssd[944363]: Starting up
Aug 20 17:47:40  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Aug 20 17:47:40  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 20 17:47:40  systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.

I tried the fixed providing in the below doc.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4948551
ie., clearing cache, stop/start service, reinstalling SSSD, rebooting instance, permission check, etc
Please note that I was able to join the AD using the realm join command without any errors.
SSSD packages installed
 sssd-common-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-ad-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-ldap-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-common-32bit-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-krb5-common-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 sssd-tools-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64
 python3-sssd-config-1.16.1-150300.23.43.1.x86_64

When trying to run SSSD daemon "sssd -d9 -i"
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:189066): [sssd] [main] (0x0400): NSCD socket was detected and it seems to be configured not to interfere with SSSD's caching capabilities
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:189252): [sssd] [check_file] (0x0400): lstat for [/var/run/sssd.pid] failed: [2][No such file or directory].
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:190504): [sssd] [ldb] (0x0400): server_sort:Unable to register control with rootdse!
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:192925): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0400): Processing config section [sssd]
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:193073): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0400): Processing attribute [config_file_version]
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:193132): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x4000): config_file_version: 2

(2024-08-20 18:30:45:193191): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0400): Processing attribute [services]
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:193246): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x4000): services: nss, pam

(2024-08-20 18:30:45:193298): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0400): Processing attribute [domains]

(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200131): [sssd] [confdb_ensure_files_domain] (0x0100): The implicit files domain is disabled
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200249): [sssd] [confdb_expand_app_domains] (0x2000):  is not an app domain
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200375): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0400): No enumeration for []!
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200426): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0400): Please note that when enumeration is disabled `getent passwd` does not return all users by design. See sssd.conf man page for more detailed information
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200524): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x1000): pwd_expiration_warning is -1
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200662): [sssd] [become_user] (0x0200): Trying to become user [0][0].
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:200804): [sssd] [become_user] (0x0200): Already user [0].
(2024-08-20 18:30:45:201067): [sssd] [ldb] (0x0400): server_sort:Unable to register control with rootdse!
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [server_setup] (0x0400): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0400): No enumeration for []!
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0400): Please note that when enumeration is disabled `getent passwd` does not return all users by design. See sssd.conf man page for more detailed information
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x1000): pwd_expiration_warning is -1
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [snotify_watch] (0x2000): Opened inotify fd 0
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [snotify_watch] (0x2000): Opened file watch 1
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [snotify_watch] (0x2000): Opened directory watch 2
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [_snotify_create] (0x0400): Added a watch for /run/netconfig/resolv.conf with inotify flags 0x8D88 internal flags 0x1 using function resolv_conf_inotify_cb after delay 1.0
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+$))|((?P<name>[^@]+)@(?P<domain>.+$))|(^(?P<name>[^@\\]+)$))].
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for : /var/lib/sss/db/cache_.ldb
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): Timestamp file for : /var/lib/sss/db/timestamps_.ldb
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [sbus_new_server] (0x0020): dbus_server_listen failed! (name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AddressInUse, message=Failed to bindsocket "/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor": Address already in use)
(2024-08-20 18:30:45): [sssd] [watch_ctx_destructor] (0x2000): Closing inotify fd 0

Please help.
SSSD needs to start and run actively
Before Joining AD.
Before joining the AD this was the error in /var/log/messages
Aug 21 11:36:34  sssd[1231272]: SSSD couldn't load the configuration database [2]: No such file or directory.
Aug 21 11:36:34  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Aug 21 11:36:34  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 21 11:36:34  systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
Aug 21 11:38:29  systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
Aug 21 11:38:29  sssd[1231736]: SSSD couldn't load the configuration database [2]: No such file or directory.
Aug 21 11:38:29  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Aug 21 11:38:29  systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 21 11:38:29  systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.

SSD LOG
(2024-08-19 17:58:39:605996): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0010): Unknown domain [DOMAIN.COM]
(2024-08-19 17:58:39:606017): [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0x0010): Error (2 [No such file or directory]) retrieving domain [DOMAIN.COM], skipping!
(2024-08-19 17:58:39:606021): [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0x0010): No properly configured domains, fatal error!
(2024-08-19 17:58:39:606025): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): No domains configured.
(2024-08-19 17:58:39:606040): [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.
(2024-08-19 18:00:56:624274): [sssd] [confdb_get_domain_internal] (0x0010): Unknown domain [DOMAIN.COM]
(2024-08-19 18:00:56:624299): [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0x0010): Error (2 [No such file or directory]) retrieving domain [DOMAIN.COM], skipping!
(2024-08-19 18:00:56:624305): [sssd] [confdb_get_domains] (0x0010): No properly configured domains, fatal error!
(2024-08-19 18:00:56:624310): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): No domains configured.
(2024-08-19 18:00:56:624327): [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.
(2024-08-19 18:06:32:560704): [sssd] [main] (0x0010): pidfile exists at /var/run/sssd.pid
(2024-08-21 11:33:08:242025): [sssd] [main] (0x0010): pidfile exists at /var/run/sssd.pid
(2024-08-21 11:36:34:780964): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0020): Attribute 'domains' has empty value, ignoring
(2024-08-21 11:36:34:787373): [sssd] [confdb_expand_app_domains] (0x0010): No domains configured, fatal error!
(2024-08-21 11:36:34:787395): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): Failed to expand application domains
(2024-08-21 11:36:34:787427): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): No domains configured.
(2024-08-21 11:36:34:787456): [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.
(2024-08-21 11:38:29:802179): [sssd] [sss_confdb_create_ldif] (0x0020): Attribute 'domains' has empty value, ignoring
(2024-08-21 11:38:29:806933): [sssd] [confdb_expand_app_domains] (0x0010): No domains configured, fatal error!
(2024-08-21 11:38:29:806951): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): Failed to expand application domains
(2024-08-21 11:38:29:806989): [sssd] [get_monitor_config] (0x0010): No domains configured.
(2024-08-21 11:38:29:807013): [sssd] [main] (0x0020): SSSD couldn't load the configuration database.

Folder permission
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root         62 Aug 21 11:35 sssd

File permission
-rw------- 1 root root 1920 Aug 21 11:35 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

SSSD conf before joining AD
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains =
# SSSD will not start if you do not configure any domains.
# Add new domain configurations as [domain/<NAME>] sections, and
# then add the list of domains (in the order you want them to be
# queried) to the "domains" attribute below and uncomment it.
; domains = LDAP

[nss]

[pam]

# Example LDAP domain
; [domain/LDAP]
; id_provider = ldap
; auth_provider = ldap
# ldap_schema can be set to "rfc2307", which stores group member names in the
# "memberuid" attribute, or to "rfc2307bis", which stores group member DNs in
# the "member" attribute. If you do not know this value, ask your LDAP
# administrator.
; ldap_schema = rfc2307
; ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.mydomain.org
; ldap_search_base = dc=mydomain,dc=org
# Note that enabling enumeration will have a moderate performance impact.
# Consequently, the default value for enumeration is FALSE.
# Refer to the sssd.conf man page for full details.
; enumerate = false
# Allow offline logins by locally storing password hashes (default: false).
; cache_credentials = true

# An example Active Directory domain. Please note that this configuration
# works for AD 2003R2 and AD 2008, because they use pretty much RFC2307bis
# compliant attribute names. To support UNIX clients with AD 2003 or older,
# you must install Microsoft Services For UNIX and map LDAP attributes onto
# msSFU30* attribute names.
; [domain/AD]
; id_provider = ldap
; auth_provider = krb5
; chpass_provider = krb5
;
; ldap_uri = ldap://your.ad.example.com
; ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
; ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
; ldap_sasl_mech = GSSAPI
; ldap_user_object_class = user
; ldap_group_object_class = group
; ldap_user_home_directory = unixHomeDirectory
; ldap_user_principal = userPrincipalName
; ldap_account_expire_policy = ad
; ldap_force_upper_case_realm = true
;
; krb5_server = your.ad.example.com
; krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM


Before joining the AD this was the error in /var/log/messages

Added in the question

Well there you are. The log states that it can't find any domain as the domain is not properly configured and that attribute has an empty value. This can be many different things. Add the contents of /etc/sssd/sssd.conf to the question.

There are also permission issues which are most likely in /etc/sssd due to incorrect ownership or permissions so that the sssd user can't access or write to that directory and its contents.

added the details

You haven't set anything in the configuration. You are still using the naked example config. You also need to configure nsswitch and krb5. If you want to use sssd, then you really don't need to join the system to AD for authentication as sssd acts as a bridge to AD that removes the need for that. If it needs to be joined to the domain for some other reason, then you are better off using openldap.

We were able to solve the SSSD connection errror.
These are the steps that we did to solve it.
In /etc/sssd/sssd.conf , change enumerate from false to true.
enumerate = True
Remove the files mentioned in the below location
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/pipes/*
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*

And recreate them.
mkdir -p /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/
touch /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor

Now restart the sssd service.
systemctl restart sssd


You must have done more than that. Enumeration being set to false and those directories wouldn't have caused the daemon to not start nor did the logs indicate that. They indicated other issues which you must have addressed unless your question isn't mentioning something.

I can confirm the permissions were correct. Joining the AD and performing the fix as above did fix the issue I faced. That I all I needed.

The error and config file indicate otherwise but sure it did.
